# How to upload an XDocument to a document library without a local hard drive path?

Tags: development, document-library, file-upload

I have seen code such as:

```
String fileToUpload = @"C:\YourFile.txt";
    String sharePointSite = "http://yoursite.com/sites/Research/";
    String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";

    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);                    

            SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

            // Prepare to upload
            Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
            String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

            // Upload document
            SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

            // Commit 
            myLibrary.Update();
        }
    }
```

That lets you upload a file to a library, but it requires a file path. I only have an XDocument and even with the SetBaseURI enabled, it won't work since the XDocument is being passed to a different computer that does not have the same file on it. Any ideas on how to get an XDocument uploaded to a library? It looks like I just need to convert the XDocument to a filestream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPFileCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412937.aspx) operates with a **Stream** object. It is not obligatory a FileStream object. It could be a MemoryStream as well. And definitely, you can pass an XDocument object to a memory stream (through XmlWriter).

So, you will need something like the following code fragment:

```
    public void UploadXDocumentToDocLib(
        XDocument document,
        string fileName,
        string siteUrl,
        string documentLibraryName,
        bool replaceExistingFile)
    {

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
                document.WriteTo(writer);
                writer.Flush();

                // get folder by url
                var folder = web.GetFolder(documentLibraryName);
                // create the file
                folder.Files.Add(fileName, stream, replaceExistingFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

There were some other inessential problems with your code:

- You don't need to update folder object when adding a file
- Better way to retrieve the folder is to use [SPWeb.GetFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461547.aspx) method, because SPWeb.Folders could fetch only root folders of the site, not their subfolders